# Is there a difference looking at max_input_vars when using ajax or normal posting?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**html**

```
<form id="saveform" method="post" action="saveform">
{a whole lot of input element}
<input type="submit" value="normal submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var data = $('#saveform').serialize();
$.post('saveform', data);
```

Is there any difference in how server handles `max_input_vars` if I

1. Post normal submit by clicking on submit-button in html above?
2. Posting entire form through ajax with jQuery above?

Would the same limit apply (for `max_input_vars`)?

**UPDATE**
A client of mine has a system I've built at a webhotell that has `max_input_vars` set to 1000 and I'm looking for a workaround because the webhotell refuses to change this number (and it's not possible to change with htaccess or php.ini). In worst case I would have to transfer my client to another webhotell but I'd rather not if there is an easy workaround.

Comment: makes sense to me the limit would be the same - i assume your asking due to an actual problem ?

Comment: @Dagon - look at the update for the actual issue :-)

Comment: You could combine multiple inputs into a single input, perhaps separated by commas or newlines, and then split them up in the server script.

Comment: because its ajax post, you could do it twice or more times just split the input first.

Comment: @Barmar - yeah I guess it would be doable. Thanks!

Comment: could send json and one var, decode into as many variables as you need

Comment: More than a thousand items in a form? How long does it take people to fill this out? Or are most of them generated automatically?

Comment: *webhotell* thats a new one to me, we call em *hosts* down here :-)

Comment: @Dagon - that's an option. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar - it's mostly automatically generated values.

Comment: also i read *(limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately)* so send half post and half get

Comment: @Dagon - haha that would work, but would be somewhat confusing in code I guess?

Comment: well work arounds are like that! - i would move host if this one is not appropriate for the client.

Comment: @Dagon - you're right. Thanks a lot for your help/input!

Comment: another option is send data in post body and extract with `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Would have empty `$_POST`

Comment: summery added as answer - any one feel free to edit (add)

Comment: @Dagon: _“(limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately) so send half post and half get”_ – apart from leading to chaotic code, this would also most likely fail quite easily due to the size limitation of GET URLs …

Comment: @CBroe, just a suggestion, not a good one i agree - but with any work-around there are problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i shall summarize the comments suggestions for future visitor reference:

the setting:  [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

**Suggestions**

- Combine multiple inputs send as one, split on server
  (Barmar,charlietfl )
- slit the data, make multiple post requests (Dagon)
- as the limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal
  separately, you can send half post and half get. (Dagon)
- Change to a host that lets you make the changes you need for the
  client (Dagon). **Most ideal if available**
- Send data in post body and extract with `file_get_contents('php://input'`). Would have empty `$_POST` (charlietfl)